# Tomcat+Apache Ubuntu.

Tags: apache-modules, jsp, java, tomcat, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток, уверен что вопрос из разряда 2+2, но реально не могу разобраться, вообщем вроди как все настроил, tomcat на *8080 слушал, все ок, свой hello world на jsp я написал...

Потом начал настраивать связку с apache, вроде как все по мануалам делал но в логе пишет

```
 [warn] No JkShmFile defined in httpd.conf. Using default /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status
```

на клиенте же - отдает 503юю. Собственно что это за файл и где он примерно лежит? чтобы я дописал в конфиге apache, или может быть даже не в нем дело? Вообщем `noob need help`, заранее спасибо :)

PS:Apache в целом нормально функционирует, 503ей ругается только на запрос `jsp` файлов... Т.е. проблема, судя по всему, именно в этом злополучном JkShmFile ^^

UPD
Оказалось что это просто очередная лог директива и проблема точно не в ней... Попрежнему отдает 503юю, лог чист, мысли закончились...

По старинке когд мыслей нет, пробую сносить все под 0 и ставить по новой :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, проблема была в настройках портов tomcat'a, сейчас все строго по ману, полет нормальный...